# What is the best way of creating Application.kt in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, messaging

My Application.kt file is like this. Could't find a way for changing *PluginRegistrantCallback* and *FlutterFirebaseMessagingService*

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService


class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(
                registry?.registrarFor(
                        "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
When I build the project I get this type error

```
e: /-/Application.kt: (6, 27): Unresolved reference: firebasemessaging
e: /-/Application.kt: (12, 9): Unresolved reference: FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
e: /-/Application.kt: (16, 28): Unresolved reference: firebasemessaging

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: `I'm in a trouble with Application.kt file in flutter` what does this mean ? how would this question title be useful to others in future with the same problem ? your question titles need to be descriptive to explain what the problem is, without people reading the content of your question

Comment: @a_local_nobody,  you are right, I will be carefully about that in future

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
package your_package_name

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry

import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin

class Application() : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
  override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
      val key: String? = FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin::class.java.canonicalName
      if (!registry?.hasPlugin(key)!!) {
          FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *hasPlugin* is depreceted, also I get *Unresolved reference: registerWith*  -_-

Answer (score 0):

You can register Firebase Messaging using `FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant`. You can see the code below for better understanding:

```
package <package_name>

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin


class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
    }
}
```

You also need to create another file namely `FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt` and put the below code inside it:

```
package <package_name>

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin

object FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant {
    fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
            return
        }
            FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))
    }

    private fun alreadyRegisteredWith(registry: PluginRegistry?): Boolean {
        val key: String? = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant::class.java.canonicalName
        if (registry?.hasPlugin(key)!!) {
            return true
        }
        registry.registrarFor(key)
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: *Unresolved reference: firebasemessaging* I change it to ***firebase.messaging*** , but again cannot solve it totally

Comment: @LalaNaibova now check

Comment: Im getting the error in this side => ***FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)***
and this part 
***FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))***